# Send two value Javascript .get()

Tags: jquery

I tried to send the one values to another file with the following script :

```
    function getDetail(){
        $.get("folder/selectfile2.php?opt2="+$("#id1").val(), function(data){   
             $("#data_detail").html(data);
          });
     }
```

This works, but I want two values. And I try the following script :

```
    function getDetail(){
        $.get("folder/selectfile2.php?opt1="+$("#id1")+"&opt2="+$("#id2").val(), function(data){   //missing value id1 
             $("#data_detail").html(data);
          });
     }
```

on >> selectfile2.php

```
$a=$_GET['opt1'];
$b=$_GET['opt2'];
echo"$a and $b";
```

but it does not work. only $b, which looks. 
is there something wrong?

Comment: Missing `.val()` from `$("#id1")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple error, maybe you were looking too hard and missed it.

**Changes:** `$("#id1")` ==> `$("#id1").val()`

```
function getDetail(){
   $.get("folder/selectfile2.php?opt1="+$("#id1").val()+"&opt2="+$("#id2").val(), function(data){   
    $("#data_detail").html(data);
   });
}
```

I hope this helps you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getDetail(){
    $.get("folder/selectfile2.php?opt1="+$("#id1").val()+"&opt2="+$("#id2").val(), function(data){   //missing value id1 
         $("#data_detail").html(data);
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you just forget .val() :) ,correct to this :

```
 function getDetail(){
        $.get("folder/selectfile2.php?opt1="+$("#id1").val()+"&opt2="+$("#id2").val(), function(data){   //missing value id1 
             $("#data_detail").html(data);
          });
     }
```